# Cannot find script setupm.js keeps popping on my screen

Tags: windows-10

Since a few days back, I started getting this message on my computer running Windows 10.

[image]

It's getting really annoying because it pops out from nowhere and at random times specially frustrating when I'm online gaming. Anyone knows what this can be? I've run full scans with my Antivirus and even Windows defender didn't detect anything.

Thanks

Comment: You can typically find the registry key for something like this with a program called AutoRuns.  As for what is causing the message to appear, something on your system is attempting to run a javascript script, that no longer exists on your system.

Comment: Search the registry for the string `setupm.js`. This might be a virus, so follow the advice in [this post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-solve-can-not-find-script-file/97707160-6320-4a11-8e01-fb6914d0fa80).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ramhound. I used AutoRuns and manage to find the script that was initiating the javascript file.

Answer (score 0):

I used AutoRuns as suggested in the comments to find what was trying to intialize that script. Managed to repair the problem.